# What is "el", what relation do these codes have with each other, and how does the fat arrow work?

Tags: javascript

I need to understand what the code means, or a better break down of how/why it works.

This function should find an object in an array called items by it's id number, and return the objects properties of which there are 9 for each object.

I've googled how the fat arrow works, but the examples given don't match this code very well, or I'm still to ignorant to see the relation. I also don't COMPLETELY understand how el is being used. I assume it's a place holder for "item" or a Boolean. I feel it's on the tip of my tongue.

pantry{

```
//.. other code of an empty array, and a function that fills the array at run time

getItem: function(id) {
    return this.items.find(el => {
        return el.id == id
    });
}
```

}

My tutor showed me that this code is equivalent to

```
     for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
         let item = items[i];

         if(item.id == id){
             return item;
         }
```

This code works as is, but I'm just barely not understanding what el does, I've changed it to ed, and do and se, and it still works, but I'm trying to understand deeply.

I'm very new to JavaScript. I've been reading "You Don't Know JavaScript" for a month now, and practicing for 3 months. I don't know if I'm learning in the best way, but I put work into learning every single day --- at any rate I digress.

Thank you for any amount of your time.

Comment: el is just a parameter of find callback function

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable

Comment: Maybe it would have been clearer if you tutor had done `for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {let el = items[i]; if (el.id == id) { return el; }}`

Answer (score 2):

`el` is just a variable. When you pass it into a function like `find`, it represents the **el**ement of the array that you are looking at during that iteration.

The arrow is just another way of defining a function. Broadly speaking, these two functions are equivilant:

```
(el) => {
    return el.id == id
});

function(el) {
    return el.id == id
}
```

You can read more about them and the differences between arrow and normal functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Thank you so much. The multiple answers from people is helping me understand better. Did I something wrong in my question to deserve -2 votes? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

for beginner simple function and arrow function are same it's just the short way of doing stuff i. e

```
function(param) {} = (param) => {} = param => {}
```

what array find function (in your case array is items) does is that it pass every item to the function and return only those item which pass the condition or return true i.e its id is equal to the given id e.g

```
arr = [{id: 2, name: 'temp'}, {id: 1, name: 'other'}]
```

on first iteration el is equal to `{id: 2, name: 'temp'}` on second iteration its equal to `{id: 1, name: 'other'}` now if the given id is 2 it will return `{id: 2, name: 'temp'}` because it pass the condition or it return true  now point to note is the el is just a name of a variable you can replace it with any name like you can replace id with other variable like tempId in `getItem: function(id)` but you have to give it only one parameter because the find function expect only one argument

Comment: Thank you so much. The multiple answers from people is helping me understand better. Did I something wrong in my question to deserve -2 votes? Thank you so much.